# Virtual deconstructor - Memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Now we have to create `class X` (as base class) and `class Y` (as derived). They both uses integer pointers to hold different size of allocations.

```
class X
{
  int *p;
  public:
         X() {p=new int[2];}
         ~X() {delete[] p;}
};

class Y : public X {
  int *q;
  public:
         Y() {q=new int[4];}
         ~Y() {delete[] q;}
};
```

And let's try it in a simple loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){X *ptr =new Y; delete ptr;}
```

What causes the memory leak there and what can we do to fix it?

Comment: I believe term "destructor" is commonly used rather than "deconstructor"

Comment: [**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) is a near-library of when/where to use virtual desructors, the case of this question being one of them.

Comment: This code has bigger problems than a memory leak.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt at a reference Q&A, but this has been done before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every execution for this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){X *ptr =new Y; delete ptr;}
```

your program first creates an integer pointer with size 2 *(2*4=8 bytes allocated)* and latter creates an integer pointer with size 4 *(4*4=16 bytes allocated)* but just deletes the first one. So for every loop, it leaks 16 bytes just because of you cannot reach the deconstructor in derived class Y.

It's called **Memory leak caused by lack of virtual deconstructor in base class**. When you make the deconstructor in class X `virtual`, then compiler will be able to delete Y-type pointers. So you have to change this statement

```
~X() {delete[] p;}
```

into this:

```
virtual ~X() {delete[] p;}
```